# How to delete specific files in unix

Tags: bash, shell, unix, unix-timestamp

We have a few files on our server instance under `/wslogs/instance_name` directory and these are all log files created on daily basis.

I am looking for a script to automatically delete those files based on date.
So lets say delete files older than 10 days. The problem is that the filename is not purely of date format rather it is

```
hostname_%m%d%Y_access.log and hostname_%m%d%Y_error.log
```

For example, `ra70960708_12042016_access.log` and `ra70960708_12042016_error.log` (where `ra70960708` is the server name or hostname).

I'm trying to use `rm` command, but unable to figure out how to specify the files here if say I have to delete those which are 10 days older from current date.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers,

Ashley

Comment: Forget about name, use modification date instead.

Comment: If the logs are generated by `logrotate`, then simply use `maxage 10`

Comment: @andlrc, Could you please elaborate what is modification date here

Comment: @RuslanOsmanov :- Could you please help me with how we can use maxage 10 here. We do use rotatelogs and the httpd.conf file has entries for these Errorlogs and Custom Logs as:-                                                                ErrorLog "| /usr/HTTPServer/bin/rotatelogs /wslogs/instance_name/`hostname`%m%d%Y_error.log 86400" CustomLog "| /usr/HTTPServer/bin/rotatelogs /wslogs/instance_name/`hostname`%m%d%Y_access.log 86400" combined

Comment: @Ashley, ah. I meant [this logrotate](https://github.com/logrotate/logrotate). Personally, I would rather use _logrotate_ instead of [piped logs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/logs.html#piped)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forgot about name, and use modification time instead:

The below will list files in current directory, that matches the glob: `hostname_*_error.log` and which are last modified +10 days ago:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 \
  -type f -name 'hostname_*_error.log' \
  -mtime +10
```

They can then be deleted with `-delete`.

`.` is the directory to search in.

Comment: @user2182349: but it would be better to use `-exec rm {} +` or, if your variant of make supports it, `-delete`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler :- could you please help me understand how we can use -exec rm {} here for the solution suggested by andlrc. Does that mean:- find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 \
  -type f -name 'hostname_*_error.log' \
  -mtime +10 -exec rm {}  It would be really great if i can have the complete unix command sets used for this purpose

Comment: @andlrc:- Thanks for the prompt solution. I will try this. However just wanted to confirm, how we can execute the whole set of commands here.Is it first find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 \
  -type f -name 'hostname_*_error.log' \
  -mtime +10 and then in a new line -delete and if yes then what do we choose to delete. Any clarifications here will really help since i'm novice in unix.

Comment: @Ashley The backslash (\\) and newlines was added for readability. If you want everything on one line it will be something like: `find . -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type f -name ... -mtime +10 -delete` It's all options for the command `find`.

Comment: @andlrc : Great, thanks for the solution and the clarifications. I will test this and see if it actually deletes all those log files dating back to 10 days and older only.

Comment: @Ashley If you omit adding `-delete` it will print the files matching the pattern. This way you can investigate before removing.

Comment: @Ashley: The 'action' part of the command should be the four arguments I showed. They follow the 'where to search' and 'conditions' part of the command.  They would appear after the `+10`.